# Calling a component gives Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made this component, `userRow`:

userRow:

```
export default function UserRow(props, {data}) {


    const style = styles();

    const userList = data.map((row) => {
      return { name: row, details: row };
    });


    return (
        <div>
        {userList.map(row => (
         <List className={style.listSize}>
           <ListItem className={style.listSize} >
               <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                    <PeopleIcon className={style.color}/>
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText className={style.text}>{props.userList.name}</ListItemText>
                <Link to={`/users/${props.userList.details}`}>
                    <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                            <ListAltIcon className={style.iconColor}/>
                     </ListItemIcon>
                </Link>
         </ListItem>
         </List>
         ))}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

I want to call it in another component, let's say in the `users` component:

users:

```
export default function User({ data })  {


  const userList = data.map((row) => {
  return { name: row, details: row };
});


  return (
        <div>
            <UserRow name={userList} details={userList} />
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Data is a json:

```
3) ["Philip J. Fry", "Turanga Leela", "Bender Bending Rodríguez"]
0: "Philip J. Fry"
1: "Turanga Leela"
2: "Bender Bending Rodríguez"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

My problem is i get  `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, i tried everything i know.
I want to call the userRow component on the users component and  display the data.

Comment: What's in `data` ? Within this `function User({ data })...`

Comment: updated the question, it's a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
export default function UserRow({ name, details }) {
    const style = styles();

    return (
        <ListItem className={style.listSize} >
            <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                <PeopleIcon className={style.color}/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText className={style.text}>{name}</ListItemText>
            <Link to={`/users/${details}`}>
                <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                    <ListAltIcon className={style.iconColor}/>
                </ListItemIcon>
            </Link>
        </ListItem>
    )
 }

 export default function User({ data })  {
    // creates the user list here
    const userList = data.map((row) => {
        return { name: row, details: row };
    });

    return (
        <List className={style.listSize}>
            {userList.map(row => (
                <UserRow name={row} details={row} />
            ))}
        </List>
    )
}
```

So, have the `UserRow` component to be JUST the row, not the full list and have the logic of mapping and creates the userList on the parent component/container.

Comment: Thanks, was missing the row.name and row,details,  but it's not possible to do it like i showed in the example? just call the component passing some data inside instead of using the map to get the data?

Comment: Yes, it's possible! If your array is just a simple array of strings, you can do like I did in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermetoti/6csbw8kL/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the props differently since the props are accumulated in the props object:

```
export default function User({ data })  {

    return (
     <div>
       <List className={style.listSize}>
        {
           data.map(row => <UserRow name={row} details={row}/>}
        }
        </List>
     </div>
    )
}
```

And access it like this:

```
export default function UserRow({details}) {


const style = styles();

return (
       <ListItem className={style.listSize} >
           <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                <PeopleIcon className={style.color}/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText className={style.text}>{props.name}</ListItemText>
            <Link to={`/users/${props.details}`}>
                <ListItemIcon className={style.listSize}>
                        <ListAltIcon className={style.iconColor}/>
                 </ListItemIcon>
            </Link>
     </ListItem>
)
}
```

Comment: Hi Domino, the solution does not display the name